# What is the property of object in fabricjs similar to css's overflow : hidden

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I am trying to make fixed size text object using fabric js.
So I tried to set the text object's left, top, width and height but that width and height is changed after entering text.
I want to hide all the overflow part.

```
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setHeight(300);
        canvas.setWidth(500);

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Tap and Type', { 
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      fontFamily: 'arial black',
      fill: '#333',
      fontSize: 50
}));
```

Is there anyone who have built text object similar to html textarea using fabric js?
I tried to find on google but not found.
Can it be done easily using fabric text object attribute?

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lvfpq57h/117/

Comment: If you hide, you cant select the hidden text.

Comment: @Durga, selecting hidden text is not needed in my case

Comment: You don't want to wrap text to next line right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is not solved as simple attribute of text object. Please see reference issue. https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/187

And here's something helpful. http://jsfiddle.net/3j352toh/19/

Here redefined `fabric.Textbox.prototype._wrapLine` to format the text as you want.

CODE:

```
fabric.Textbox.prototype._wrapLine = function(ctx, text, lineIndex) {
    var lineWidth        = 0,
        lines            = [],
        line             = '',
        words            = text.split(' '),
        word             = '',
        letter           = '',
        offset           = 0,
        infix            = ' ',
        wordWidth        = 0,
        infixWidth       = 0,
        letterWidth      = 0,
        largestWordWidth = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        word = words[i];
        wordWidth = this._measureText(ctx, word, lineIndex, offset);
        lineWidth += infixWidth;

        // Break Words if wordWidth is greater than textbox width
        if (this.breakWords && wordWidth > this.width) {
            line += infix;
            var wordLetters = word.split('');
            while (wordLetters.length) {
                letterWidth = this._getWidthOfChar(ctx, wordLetters[0], lineIndex, offset);
                if (lineWidth + letterWidth > this.width) {
                    lines.push(line);
                    line = '';
                    lineWidth = 0;
                }
                line += wordLetters.shift();
                offset++;
                lineWidth += letterWidth;
            }
            word = '';
        } else {
            lineWidth += wordWidth;
        }

        if (lineWidth >= this.width && line !== '') {
            lines.push(line);
            line = '';
            lineWidth = wordWidth;
        }

        if (line !== '' || i === 1) {
            line += infix;
        }
        line += word;
        offset += word.length;
        infixWidth = this._measureText(ctx, infix, lineIndex, offset);
        offset++;

        // keep track of largest word
        if (wordWidth > largestWordWidth && !this.breakWords) {
            largestWordWidth = wordWidth;
        }
    }

    i && lines.push(line);

    if (largestWordWidth > this.dynamicMinWidth) {
        this.dynamicMinWidth = largestWordWidth;
    }

    return lines.slice(0,this.cHeight/this.lineHeight/this.fontSize);
};

var _fabric = new fabric.Canvas('breaker');
_fabric.setBackgroundColor('#eee', _fabric.renderAll.bind(_fabric));

var curWidth = document.getElementById('breaker').width;
var curHeight = document.getElementById('breaker').height;
var longText="ABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEFABCDEFEF";
var breakingTextbox = new fabric.Textbox(longText,
    {
        width: curWidth / 2,
        cHeight: curHeight/2,
        left: curWidth / 2,
        top: 180,
        fill: '#333',
        cursorWidth: 0.5,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'top',
        textAlign: 'center',
        breakWords: true
});
_fabric.add(breakingTextbox).setActiveObject(breakingTextbox);
breakingTextbox.enterEditing();
```

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: @junkai, your link is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`Textbox`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Textbox.html) class instead of the `Text`.

It is editable by default and will wrap the text when not fitting the width. (*it will not hide it as `overflow:hidden` but will work as a `textarea` where the text wraps*)

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Tap and Type', {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Lvfpq57h/118/

Comment: Thanks, but your fiddle changes the height and width after typing, I want to hide the overflow text after typing